# Unable to update object inside state in React

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native and trying to update the variable which is actually in object and that object is in state object I have tried other solutions which were provided but none of them seems working in my code.Please help me to identify whether I am doing something wrong in the code or is there is any other way to update the state of an objectI have also added what actual error message is being shown in emulator.Thanks in advance.

```
constructor(props){
 super(props);
  state={
    firstName:{
      errorName:true,
      firstname:'',
    }
  }
 }
onNameChange=(name)=>{
  this.setState(prevState => {
    let firstName = Object.assign({}, prevState.firstName);       
       firstName.firstname = name;             
        return { firstName }; 
      })
}

<FloatLabel inputStyle={styletheme.inputLabel}
            labelStyle={styletheme.labelInput}
            style={styletheme.formInput}
            onChangeText={(firstname)=> {
                this.onNameChange(firstname)
                }
             }     
>
                   First Name
```

[image: error message]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using the spread operator to update the value? and try something like this?

```
constructor(props){
 super(props);
  this.state={
    firstName:{
      errorName:true,
      firstname:'Namrata',
    }
  }
 }
onNameChange=(name)=>{
  //This will make copy of firstName in state and assign it to firstName (read about spread Operator) 
  const firstName = {...this.state.firstName}

  //Once we have made a copy of the property, we are updating the firstName property name 
   firstname.name = name 

   //Now we are storing that new property to this.setState, since we previously made the copy of firstName and then updated that copy, We don't need to use `prevState`
  // setState will set that updated property firstName to the firstName in our this.setState
  this.setState({firstName: firstName })
}
```

Also, In your code

**Note 1:** 
this `return { firstName };` seems wrong, In your code`firstName` does not have property firstName. So destructing firstName should give undefined. if you want to return, just do `return firstName`

**Note 2:** You can't do just `state=` in constructor, you need to do `this.state=` since scope of `state` would only be inside the `constructor` if you use `state` without doing `this.state`

For starters in your `onNameChange` if you do a `console.log(this.state)`, it should come out to be undefined

```
 onNameChange=(name)=>{
      console.log(this.state)
```

Probably, you would have confused it with `state` outside the constructor

```
constructor(props){
 super(props);
}
state={
    firstName:{
      errorName:true,
      firstname:'Namrata',
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @iRohitBhatia I have tried the above method but that shows some error.Error message : null is not an object (evaluating '_this.state.firstName')

Comment: @RohitBhatia I have taken both the points into considering neither of them seems working nor your solution is working and I am really sorry I have misplaced one variable now you can see my updated code but that throws an error.Can't find variable firstname.

Comment: Thanks @RohitBhatia now the code seems working it's just I have mixed some variable names it's really awesome I have tried almost every solution none of them seems working but yours solution worked out in my code.

Comment: @NamrataSanger Have you used some library for `<FloatLabel`? I have never used floatlabel but here  `onChangeText={(firstname)=> {`,  Are you sure that you are passing `firstName` correctly?

Comment: @NamrataSanger Perfect, If this works mark the answer - answered. Glad to be able to help :)

Comment: @RohitBhatia can you just explain the second line of your code firstName.firstname=name how that works actually I am confused isn't it we have to update the state in setState and without writing this line of code in setState how it is updating the state.

Comment: @NamrataSanger Added comments in the above code snippet. Go through them, probably that will help you